# How do I append reviews text and reviews rating to a list

Tags: python, nlp, text-mining

I am writing a program which analyses online reviews and based on the ratings, stores the review into `review_text` and the corresponding rating into `review_label` as either positive(4 & 5 stars) or negative(1, 2 & 3 stars).

Tried the following codes to add the review text and review label information of each review without any success.

```
rev = ['review_text', 'review_label']
for file in restaurant_urls:
    url_rev= file
    html_r_r=requests.get(url_rev).text
    doc_rest=html_r_r

    soup_restaurant_content= BeautifulSoup(doc_rest, 'html.parser')
    star_text = soup_restaurant_content.find('img').get('alt')
    if star_text in ['1-star','2-star','3-star']:
        rev['review_label'].append('Negative')
    elif star_text in ['4-star','5-star']:
        rev['review_label'].append('Positive')
    else:
        print('check')
    rev['review_text'].append(soup_restaurant_content.find('p','text').get_text())
```

I want the reviews to be stored in the list `rev` with the review text stored in column `review_text` and the review label (whether positive or negative) under `review_label`. It would look something like

```
'review_text'    'review_label'
 review_1         positive
 review_2         negative
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are misunderstanding how lists work because lists do not have columns. In your case, `rev` is a list with two items, and you can add new items to the list (e.g. `rev.append('review_user')` will result in `rev` looking like this: `['review_text', 'review_label', 'review_user']`). However, you cannot add an item to an item in the list (which it seems you are trying to do with `rev['review_label'].append('Negative')`).

In this specific case, I think the best solution is to have two separate lists, one for the review texts and one for the review labels, and append the respective items accordingly:

```
review_text = []
review_label = []

...

review_text.append(SOMETEXT)
review_label.append(SOMELABEL)
```

If you then want to have the data in a data frame, you can use pandas like so:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.DataFrame({"review_text": review_text, "review_label": review_label})
```

This should give you what you want. Note that `review_text` and `review_label` have to have the same length (which they should, in your case).
I hope this helps! Comment if you have any questions.

Comment: Thank you so much for such a detailed explanation.  I did make the changes you suggested me and I created lists review_text = [] and review_label = [] and it works absolutely fine now.